# SAP UI5 CDS Annotation, set search filter label

Tags: sapui5, cds

I'm new to SAP and UI5. I have created a table in SE11 and created a CDS view in eclipse ABAP perspective. And I've create a template project in my SAP Web Ide.

I want to change the display label of a selection field. It currenty show the name I've given by for the table column data type. Ex:. For factoryId column I've given the data type named FactoryCode. It shows the FactoryCode label in the selection field. I want to change it to "Factory".

I've used UI.lineItem.label annotation, but it only changed the grid column name only. How to change the filter label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this annotation @EndUserText.label: 'Factory'.